# Alarm Manager at Phone Reboot

Tags: android, alarmmanager, bootcompleted

i'm developing a reminder application for my java subject.

I'm using this code to create my pending alarm, here's the code.

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(ReminderActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                intent2.putExtra("idint", iid);
                intent2.putExtra("title", myRem.getText().toString());
                intent2.putExtra("title_desc", myRemDesc.getText().toString());
                intent2.putExtra("date", date.toString());
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(ReminderActivity.this,iid, intent2,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And i have set up my AndroidManifest.xml to add my receiver on boot

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name="PollReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And lastly, this is my PollReceiver.class

```
public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  static DBAdapter db;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
  }

  static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
    db.open();
     Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
     if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                int iid = (int) c.getLong(0);
                String title = c.getString(1);
                String title_desc = c.getString(2);
                String date = c.getString(3);

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date myDate = null;
                    try {
                        myDate = sdf.parse(date);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(myDate);

                Calendar CurCal = Calendar.getInstance();

                if (cal.compareTo(CurCal) <= 0 )
                {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ctxt, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent2.putExtra("idint", iid);
                    intent2.putExtra("title", title);
                    intent2.putExtra("title_desc", title_desc);
                    intent2.putExtra("date", date);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
                            PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt,iid, intent2,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            }

            } while(c.moveToNext());

        }

        db.close();

  }
}
```

But it seems, still it doesn't reload my pending alarms.

any wild guess guys?

Comment: For reference (with downloadable code - tested: works): http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Some devices are weird about BOOT_COMPLETED. I know I ran into issues where it wasn't detecting it on my HTC (since it didn't do full boots on restart). Try adding this to your manifest: <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

Comment: another thing, do this boot_completed works on emulators?

Comment: Depends on the emulator and how it is set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive that your alarm is properly configured and the problem is that you are not receiving the "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE" action, then take this on count:

> As an anti-malware move by Google. Google has advocated that
>   users should launch an activity from the launcher first, before the
>   application can do much, preventing BOOT_COMPLETED from being
>   delivered until the activity is launched explicitly at least once.

Is a common mistake on recent android verions.

Regards!

Comment: my alarms works fine without restarting, i'm wondering here

    <receiver android:name="PollReceiver"> 

is it the same with <receiver android:name=".PollReceiver">?

another thing i'm making my pending intent getActivity not getBroadcast . Because all my searches uses getBroadcast on their pending intent.

Comment: you should use getBroadcast, because the class PollReceiver extends from BroadcastReceiver(or at least it should because in your manifest you declared it as receiver), and you need to set it as ".PollReceiver", also read a good android book whenever you have the chance to if you want to really learn about the OS...

Comment: sorry for being beginner. i will search more.